# Heading and Menu for page stops at scroll point HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, scroll

So I have one page on my website that is pretty wide, and has to be horizontally scrolled in order to see all of its contents if its on my smaller monitor screen. However, when I scroll, the header and menu and their stylings just stop. Like this:
[image]

Here is my HTML for the section:

```
<!--website main heading layout-->
<div id="heading">
    <h1> Beat Your Pace <h1/>
    <h2> The music search tool to boost your running performance! </h2>
</div>

<!--topbar/menu layout-->
<div id="topbar">
<div id="topbar_wrapper">
    <ul id="mainmenu">
        <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li><li>
        <a href="search.php">Search</a></li><li>
        <a href='add_song.php'>Add Song</a></li><li>
        <a href='about.php'>About</a></li><li>
        <a href="contact_us.php">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS for the section;

```
#heading {
background: url("http://cdn4.techlila.com/wp-    content/uploads/2011/01/header2.jpg");
background-position: -50% 50%;
color: LightGrey;
font-weight:900;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #000;
width: 100%;
}

#heading h1, h2 {
margin: 0px;
padding: 5px;
}

#topbar {
background-color: #222;
}
#topbar_wrapper {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
}





#mainmenu {
list-style-type: none;
padding-left: 0px;
margin: 0px;
position: relative;
min-width: 200px;
}
#mainmenu > li {
display: inline-block;
width: 200px;
}
#mainmenu li:hover {
background-color: #333;
}
#mainmenu li a{
color: #CCC;
display: block;
padding: 15px;
text-decoration: none;
}

#mainmenu li:hover > ul {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: 1. I can't see the difference between the layouts; 2. Do not access WP theme images with direct URL (use relative paths instead); 3. Try not to mix single quote & double quote in same HTML; 4. Try to indent / format your codes.

Comment: there is not difference. They are the same layout, but I want the page header and menu to extend all the way to the right in the second image.

Comment: See the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You need a wrapper DIV to put everything you need to align width inside.

The wrapper CSS is as follow:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
```

Working demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shivanraptor/3h1ew20m/)